# Suppress warning "Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [...] because it is marked as final:" for a specific class only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, suppress-warnings, cglib

In a Spring application we have several warnings like this:

```
o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [...] 
because it is marked as final: 
Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12690349/2886891) and its answers describe well the whole issue:

> Using CGLIB has a limitation that methods marked as final in target class can’t be advised as final methods can’t be overridden (CGLIB creates a subclass of target class at runtime) but this limitation disappears in case of using JDK dynamic proxies.

There are situations where you simply need to use it, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45277568/2886891).

The solutions I found say more or less *Don't worry, it is only a warning, you may decrease the log level if you don't like to see it*.

My **question** is more specific: **Is it possible to suppress the warning for a specific class only?** We do not want to suppress all the warnings, just the ones where we know that what we are doing is on purpose.

Version:

- Spring Boot Starter: 2.0.0.M3
- Spring: 5.0.0.RC3

Comment: No there isn't unless you write your own logging appender which has that knowledge... Otherwise you could only suppress the logging for the `o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy` by setting the level for that logger to `ERROR`.

Comment: @M.Deinum if you are sure with your comment could you please turn it into an answer with a small hint as for how to write my own login appender "which has that knowledge" - did you mean which textually parses what is being logged and filters out based on a regular expression or so?

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you wish to turn your comment into an answer? :) It would make sense to have the question answered...