# Spring Unable to proxy interface

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, spring-data

My DAOImpl is looking like:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
    }



  @Override
  public List<User> getUsers(String client) {

    DataSource dataSource = getDsHolder().getClientDataSource(client, this.getClass().getName());
    this.setDataSource(dataSource);
    List<User> users = getJdbcTemplate().query(DEFAULT_SELECT_USER, new UserRowMapper());
     if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users;
     } else {
        return Collections.emptyList();
     }

    }
}
```

My DataSource class is looking like:

```
   public BasicDataSource createClientDataSource(String clientName) {
    String jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    String jdbcUrl = env.getProperty("jdbc.url");
    String jdbcUsername = env.getProperty("jdbc.user");
    String jdbcPassword = env.getProperty("jdbc.password");

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriver);
    dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl + clientName + "?autoReconnectForPools=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
    dataSource.setUsername(jdbcUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(jdbcPassword);
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");
    return dataSource;
    }
```

And when i start my spring boot application i`m getting:

```
INFO 2022-02-02 15:54:35,643 [main] 263 - Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException,org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

But i can't find a way how to change it to not showing this message.

Comment: Disable INFO logging.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584851/suppress-warning-unable-to-proxy-interface-implementing-method-because-it